# PySpark PythonUDF Missing input attributes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to use Spark SQL Data Frame to read some data in and apply a bunch of text clean up functions to each row.

```
import langid
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hsC = HiveContext(sc)
df = hsC.sql("select * from sometable")

def check_lang(data_str):
    language = langid.classify(data_str)
    # only english
    record = ''
    if language[0] == 'en':
        # probability of correctly id'ing the language greater than 90%
        if language[1] > 0.9:
            record = data_str
    return record

check_lang_udf = udf(lambda x: check_lang(x), StringType())

clean_df = df.select("Field1", check_lang_udf("TextField"))
```

However when I attempt to run this I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.select.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Unable to evaluate PythonUDF.  Missing input attributes
```

I've spent a good deal trying to gather up more information on this but I can't find anything.

As a sidenote, I know the code below works but I'd like to stay with dataframes.

```
removeNonEn = data.map(lambda record: (record[0], check_lang(record[1])))
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `check_lang_udf("TextField"))` with `check_lang_udf(df.TextField))`?

Comment: @zero323 tried that as well. No luck. I'm on v 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this code, but from the API docs suggest this should work:

```
hsC.registerFunction("check_lang", check_lang)
clean_df = df.selectExpr("Field1", "check_lang('TextField')")
```

Comment: Can you link to where in the docs you found that? It doesn't crash but it seems to always return an empty string. I even tried with another function  `def check_lang(data_str):
    language = langid.classify(data_str)
    return language[0]`

Comment: Actually on second look looks like in the `registerFunction` you need to include a return type. So it should actually be `hsC.registerFunction("check_lang", lambda x: check_lang(x), StringType())` and then run with `df = df.selectExpr("Field1", "TextField", "check_lang(TextField) as lang")`

Comment: I think you only need a return type if it's not StringType. Still, it's not a bad idea to add that just in case and for clearer documentation :-)